# How to create ranges and synonym constants in C#?

Tags: c#, typedef

I've just started working in C#, and I would like to define a new type (`Priority`) as an integer, going from 1 to 9. In top of this, I would like to create three new constants:

```
pri_Low,     which has value 1
pri_Default, which has value 5
pri_High,    which has value 9
```

I though of doing something like this: (C-style)

```
typedef TPriority = 1..9;
Const TPriority pri_Low     1;
Const TPriority pri_Default 5;
Const TPriority pri_High    9;
```

But when I look for this on the internet, I get answers like "You need to create a class, and you need to declare it `static`, and ...".

My first reaction is "Hold your horses. I just want to create a simple range of numbers and give a meaning to three of them. No classes, no constructors, no `static`, `public`, `private`, `friend` or whatever fancy things, just simple basics.", is this even possible or is C# that into "Everything is a class" that such simple things are not even allowed?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types

Comment: There is no numeric **subset** type in C# or .NET. You will have to create one if you need one. And yes, you have a bit of code to write if you want one.

Comment: c# has enum built-in type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum

Comment: @MaximKosov: The `enum` is the opposite of what I'm looking for: `enum` means "You can declare a full list of meanings, and for some of them, you can assign a value.", but what I'm looking for is a value range (from 1 to 9) and just for some of them (1, 5 and 9) I would like to create a constant, which has the same type definition of the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a ... No, you don't **need** to do anything.

You can, however, implement a relatively simple type. I say relatively because on first glance it will look like a lot of code, but the code itself is really simple.

And yes, coming from Object Pascal / Delphi, which has the 1..9 types, I really miss those types, but sadly they don't exist in C# or .NET.

In C# 8, we got "ranges", but they're not types, they're just values.

Now, on the **simple** and naive end you can use an enum:

```
public enum Priority
{
    Low = 1,
    Default = 5,
    High = 9
}
```

However, you now don't have a priority for 4, and if you want to ask .NET to tell you if a value is valid or not, you need to have names for all valid values, so you would need:

```
public enum Priority
{
    P1 = 1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9,
    
    Low = P1,
    Default = P5,
    High = P9
}
```

Unfortunately, enums doesn't prevent you from storing invalid values, this is fine:

```
Priority p = (Priority)-5;
```

and any fields in a type that you don't explicitly assign a value will have the value `(Priority)0` as default, not 5.

So...

If you want a type that actually doesn't accept values less than 1 or higher than 9, you have no recurse than to create one yourself, so here's a simple Priority type for the range 1..9:

```
public struct Priority : IEquatable<Priority>, IEquatable<int>,
    IComparable<Priority>, IComparable<int>, IFormattable
{
    private const int _lowPriority = 1;
    private const int _defaultPriority = 5;
    private const int _highPriority = 9;
    
    private readonly int _value;
    
    public Priority(int value)
    {
        if (value < _lowPriority || value > _highPriority)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value),
                $"value must be in the range {_lowPriority}..{_highPriority}");
            
        _value = value - _defaultPriority;
    }

    // the trick with `+/- _defaultPriority` is to make sure
    // new Priority() is the same as new Priority(5)
    public int Value => _value + _defaultPriority;

    public static Priority Parse(string s)
        => Parse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
    public static Priority Parse(string s, NumberStyles style,
        IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        if (TryParse(s, style, provider, out var priority))
            return priority;
        throw new FormatException($"Unable to parse priority '{s}'");
    }
    
    public static bool TryParse(string s, out Priority result)
        => TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo,
               out result);
    public static bool TryParse(string s, NumberStyles style,
        IFormatProvider provider, out Priority result)
    {
        result = default;
        if (s is null)
            return false;
            
        var span = s.AsSpan();
        if (span.Length == 0 || span[0] != 'P')
            return false;
        span = span[1..];
        
        if (!int.TryParse(span, style, provider, out int value))
            return false;
            
        if (value < _lowPriority || value > _highPriority)
            return false;
            
        result = new Priority(value);
        return true;
    }
    
    public static readonly Priority Low = new Priority(_lowPriority);
    public static readonly Priority Default = new Priority(_defaultPriority);
    public static readonly Priority High = new Priority(_highPriority);
    
    public static implicit operator int(Priority priority) => priority.Value;
    public static explicit operator Priority(int value) => new Priority(value);
    
    public static bool operator ==(Priority a, int b) => a.Value == b;
    public static bool operator !=(Priority a, int b) => a.Value != b;
    public static bool operator <(Priority a, int b) => a.Value < b;
    public static bool operator >(Priority a, int b) => a.Value > b;
    public static bool operator <=(Priority a, int b) => a.Value <= b;
    public static bool operator >=(Priority a, int b) => a.Value >= b;

    public static bool operator ==(int a, Priority b) => a == b.Value;
    public static bool operator !=(int a, Priority b) => a != b.Value;
    public static bool operator <(int a, Priority b) => a < b.Value;
    public static bool operator >(int a, Priority b) => a > b.Value;
    public static bool operator <=(int a, Priority b) => a <= b.Value;
    public static bool operator >=(int a, Priority b) => a >= b.Value;
    
    public bool Equals(Priority other) => Value == other.Value;
    public bool Equals(int other) => Value == other;
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Priority other
        && Equals(other);
    public override int GetHashCode() => _value.GetHashCode();
    
    public int CompareTo(Priority other) => Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
    public int CompareTo(int other) => Value.CompareTo(other);

    public override string ToString() => $"P{Value}";
    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        => $"P{Value.ToString(format, formatProvider)}";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I fully agree. If you need lots of ranges like this you can probably create a source generator that generates all this code for you, so that it is easy for you to construct types for new ranges with new value boundaries. But, yes, more code than in Delphi.